# How to get the classic Jenkins build status icons back?

Tags: jenkins

From my POV the classic Jenkins build status icons were, and still are, a masterpiece of icon art:

[image]

All the others weren't, and still aren't, bad either. (How is the saying? "If it ain't broke, don't break it!"? :)

While I appreciate that the new ones are SVGs, this [image] looks more like a [shuriken](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuriken) that killed my build, rather than a sun and this cloud [image] looks boringly simplified compared to the classic one, looks like being drawn in a 101 MS Paint class.

How can I get the classic icons back into my Jenkins instance? They're still all there in the `jenkins.war`.

Answer (score 4):

That [icon change](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/pull/5065) did not go over well. [JENKINS-65124](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-65124) was raised as a result.

The change did two things:

- It overhauled the how the images are consumed such that they are served up as SVG now. The new ones are now served up from:  `${JENKINS_HOME}/war/images/build-status/weather-sprite.svg`, along with the build-status icons from `.../build-status-sprite.svg`
- It replaced the "Classic icons" from the [Tango Pproject](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Tango_icons) with new flat icons from [jenkins-core-theme](https://github.com/jenkins-contrib-themes/jenkins-core-theme/tree/master/images). The Tango icons were not incorporated into the weather-sprite.svg.

I was not a fan of the Classic icons (too convoluted for 48px or smaller) or new set (see Jenkins issue), so I took a stab at an alternate set, available attached to the issue as [weather-jenkins.svg](https://issues.jenkins.io/secure/attachment/55120/weather-jenkins.svg); just rename to `weather-sprite.svg` and drop into the exploded war location.

Your solution to get the Classic icons back would be to incorporate the SVG for the five Tango icons into `weather-sprite.svg` in place of the existing definitions. Unfortunately, the straight replace does not render properly, resulting in a loss of the gradient shading (which makes up most of the SVG definitions). I don't know enough about SVG to sort it out.

btw: [cross-posting](https://superuser.com/questions/1684695/how-to-get-the-classic-jenkins-icons-back) is usually frowned upon, but also reinforces my meta concern that no one knows where to [post Jenkins issues](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/412698/598141) w/o proper guidance.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm going to give the `weather-jenkins.svg` try. I know about cross-posting but this is just beta here and at looking at the overall questions list it seemed to me half-live only. Or half-dead the other way round.

Comment: Download [this zip file](https://issues.jenkins.io/secure/attachment/54981/weather-symbols.zip) in order to first take a look at the graphics.